# Finding the indices where a selected player appears in a list of hashes

Tags: performance, beginner, ruby, array

I have an array of hashes in a YAML file. When I run the code below it is VERY slow. My YAML `pwsarr.count` is about 2000.

I am somewhat new to Ruby so I don't know if my code is not efficient or if I am doing something wrong. I know it loops my array before it's in the method and it loops in the method, but I wouldn't think it would make it as slow as it is.

```
def pwsplayerindex(inplayer)
    #returns array of indicies of selected player
    #if one player is in array twice you will get 2 indicies #s
    #pwsarr my array of hashes

arr = []

    pwsarr.each_with_index do |val,index|
            if val['player'] == inplayer 
                arr << index  
            end
    end
arr
end

for j in 0..pwsarr.count
    puts pwsplayerindex(pwsarr[j]['player'])
end
```

my array of hashes is something like this:

```
pwsarr =[{'player'=>'first1 last1', 'stat'=>0.0},{'player'=>'first2 last2', 'stat'=>0.0}]
```

Comment: Could you give us some background about _why_ you want to find the indices in the first place? Perhaps you are solving an unnecessary problem?

Comment: Each index in my pwsarr array represents a player with their stats for the week. There are duplicate players because the same player plays each week. So a player may have index numbers 1,5,66. The method above cycles pwsarr and finds these index numbers. I then use those number in a different method to get all the players stats from pwsarr and run calculations on. I want to run the calculations on ALL players.  @Peilonrayz answer is a smart way of doing this but the key in my hash could not have duplicate  players because keys are unique which causes me problems.

Comment: find something other than `each_with_index`. I read on `ruby-performance-book.com` that it actually "produces 2 extra Ruby objects."

Comment: I used a for loop and counted the cycles instead of using 'each_with_index' it was not any faster, but thanks.

Comment: What kind of calculations do you want to calculate? Counts, averages, and sums? Does the order of the entries matter? Ideally, you should include statistics-calculating code in the question too.

Comment: The order doesn't matter. I am calculating standard deviation and a modified version of standard deviation of the data for a single player for every game they play(but I need to do it for all players). I believe I need to organize my data better before I calculate what I need. I just don't know the best way. An array of hashes is not the right way I know that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is calling an \$O(n)\$ function \$n\$ times. This leads to \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity on the whole. Instead I'd make a function to change `pwsarr` to a Hash, where the key is the player name, and the value is a list of 'player objects'. This can then cause your program to be \$O(n)\$ as hash lookup is \$O(1)\$.

The loop can then become: (I don't know Ruby.)

```
pwsarr = [
    {'player'=>'first1 last1', 'stat'=>0.0},
    {'player'=>'first1 last1', 'stat'=>2.0},
    {'player'=>'first2 last2', 'stat'=>0.0}
]

def group_by(list_hash, key)
    h = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] }

    for hash in list_hash do
        h[hash[key]].push(hash)
    end
    h
end

pws_by_player = group_by(pwsarr, 'player')
for player in pwsarr do
    puts pws_by_player[player['player']]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This would be the best way to do it but my array has duplicate players. If I use an array they are identified by the index #. I don't believe I can use a hash because my key values will not be unique. I think I do have to reorganize my array a different way though.

Comment: @ryanhall And that's why I said to use a list of player objects, :P When I fix my pc, I'll look into writing the function `group_players`

Comment: I am not sure how doing that made it less complex, but it did! It calculates 100 times faster. I appreciate the help @Peilonrayz.